# C# lambda expression for getting the group by and count

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have C# data and want to use Normal data looks like below

```
ID           Count   Client      MessageType
1   100 MegaTech    Missing SO
2   100 MegaTech    Not shipped
3   100 NIXIMIXI     No PDF
4   100 MegaTech    Missing SO
5   100 NIXIMIXI     Not shipped
6   100 MegaTech    No PDF
7   100 NIXIMIXI    Other
8   100 MegaTech    Other
9   100 MegaTech    No PDF
10  100 NIXIMIXI    Missing SO
11  100 MegaTech    Not shipped
12  100 NIXIMIXI    No PDF
13  100 MegaTech    Missing SO
14  100 NIXIMIXI    Not shipped
15  100 NIXIMIXI    No PDF
16  100 MegaTech    other
17  100 NIXIMIXI    other
18  100 NIXIMIXI    other
```

So I want out put of the list like below and the message Type other may contains empty space or null values.

```
ID       Count   Client      MessageType
1   100 MegaTech    Missing SO
2   100 MegaTech    Missing SO
3   100 MegaTech    No PDF
4   100 MegaTech    No PDF
5   100 MegaTech    No PDF
6   100 MegaTech    Not shipped
7   100 MegaTech    Not shipped
8   100 MegaTech    Other
9   100 MegaTech    Other
10  Total For   9      Total Items    900
11  100 NIXIMIXI    Missing SO
12  100 NIXIMIXI    Missing SO
13  100 NIXIMIXI    No PDF
14  100 NIXIMIXI    No PDF
15  100 NIXIMIXI    Not shipped
16  100 NIXIMIXI    Not shipped
17  100 NIXIMIXI    other
18  100 NIXIMIXI    other
19  100 NIXIMIXI    other

20  Total For   9      Total Items  900
```

I want to use Linq or Lambda expression for the this.
I have use like this but do not know how put the count column.

```
 listEOMRep = listEOMRep.OrderBy(x => x.client).ThenBy(x => x.MessageType).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not excactly as you want it, but it gets the job done I guess:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = new List<CustomObject>() 
    {
        new CustomObject() {Id = 1, Count = 100, Client = "MegaTech", MessageType = "Not Shipped" },
        new CustomObject() {Id = 2, Count = 250, Client = "NIXIMIXI", MessageType = "Not Shipped" },
        new CustomObject() {Id = 3, Count = 45, Client = "NIXIMIXI", MessageType = "No PDF" },
        new CustomObject() {Id = 4, Count = 10, Client = "MegaTech", MessageType = "Not Shipped" },
        new CustomObject() {Id = 5, Count = 100, Client = "MegaTech", MessageType = "No PDF" },
        new CustomObject() {Id = 6, Count = 100, Client = "NIXIMIXI", MessageType = "Not Shipped" },
        new CustomObject() {Id = 7, Count = 100, Client = "NIXIMIXI", MessageType = "Not Shipped" },
        new CustomObject() {Id = 8, Count = 140, Client = "MegaTech", MessageType = "other" }
    };

    var result = source.OrderBy(x => x.Client)
                       .ThenBy (x => x.MessageType)
                       .GroupBy (s => s.Client)
                       .Select (s => new {
                            Key = s.Key,
                            Object = s,
                            TotalFor = s.Count(),
                            TotalItems = s.Sum(x => x.Count)
                       })
                       .Dump();
}

public class CustomObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

[image]